# Qt Designer, кнопка не хочет менять свои параметры

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qss, qpushbutton

Кнопка не хочет менять свои параметры, что очень странно ведь другие элементы их меняют. Не понимаю в чем проблема?

[image: Скрин проблемы]

---

Пример кода:

```
QPushButton {
   font: 20pt "Century Gothic";
   color: #f2b824;
   background-color: #1d1c21:
   border: none;
}
 
QPushButton:hover {
   color: #f2c44e;
   background-color: #3a3c42;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
   color: #eb7b13
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте так:

1. Набросали виджеты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Добавили `Font`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Добавили `color` и `background-color`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Выполнили `Apply` и `OK`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. Добавили нужные вам вещи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6. Все, готово.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Diareich получилось ?

Comment: Да, ваш ответ помог. Похоже, что у них очень в PyQT5 классы очень кривые или у меня руки, как вариант. Я немного в замешательстве ведь, если создавать через интерфейс и даже если потом свои рукописные значения ввести и запихать их в классы все работает. В чем фича, мб где нибудь еще нада прописывать в ручную, если не через интерфейс создаешь ? (p.s. ::: У меня такая же проблема с шарпами была, когда через винформс графику пилил, в итоге там просто в нескольких местах надо было прописывать кодом)